# Python 3.8.2 の IDLE で10進数を2~10進数に変換するプログラムを作りたい

Tags: python, python3, python-idle

python初学者で、小数を含む10進数を2~10進数(2,8進数)に変換するプログラムを書いています。
if文だけだと思うように動くのですが、else文を入れるとinvalid syntaxとエラーが返ってきてしまいます。
ちなみにif文ではaの値(入力される10進数の数)が整数であるか。elseでは小数の場合と判別しています。
Python 3.8.2 の IDLE を使っています。
どなたかご教授お願いします。

```
import math
a=float(input('10進数の数字'))
b=int(input('変換したい進数'))
result=''
first_digit=''
#tは小数部 fは整数部
(t,f)=math.modf(a)
i=int(f)
if t==0.0:
    while i>0:
        result+=str(i%b)
        i=i//b
    print(result[::-1])

else:
    while i>0:
        result+=str(i%b)
        i=i//b
    (z,t)=math.modf(float(t))
    while z!=0.0:
        t=str(t*b)
        first_digit+=t[0]
        (z,t)=math.modf(float(t))
    total=float(result[::-1])+float(first_digit)
    print(total)
```

Comment: 参考までに、numpy には [base_repr](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html) があります(整数値で2~36進数に対応)。`base_repr` のソースコードは [base_repr in numpy/numeric.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2055) です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.25(10) -> 110.01(2) こんな感じにしたいのなら

```py
import math
a=float(input('10進数の数字'))
b=int(input('変換したい進数'))
first_digit=''
#tは少数部　fは整数部
sgn = '-' if a < 0 else ''
a = math.fabs(a)
(t,f) = math.modf(a)
i = int(f)
result = '' if i != 0 else '0'
while i > 0:
    result += str(i%b)
    i //= b
z = t
f_limit = 10 # 適当
while z != 0.0:
    t = str(z * b)
    first_digit += t[0]
    (z,t) = math.modf(float(t))
    f_limit -= 1
    if f_limit <= 0:
        break
if first_digit != '':
    first_digit = '.' + first_digit
print( sgn + result[::-1] + first_digit )
```